# Is it possible to have a root path containing spaces in my nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have tried escaping (and not escaping), with (and without) single quotes double qoutes but i always end up on the 404 page.

is it even possible? i tried searching for it, but landed of https://serverfault.com/questions/361915/how-can-i-make-nginx-recognise-directories-with-spaces-in-its-name but i already tried that, and it didnt work.

if this i just me, then please prove it to me :)

Comment: It is just you. Copy your scripts to e temporary directory w/o spaces and make that work. Then you'll be able to fix the initial path pretty fast. Cheers :)

Comment: it did what you said, and its works, and now i feel stupid. thanks for helping out. i have no freaking idea why it didnt work before. thanks again.

Comment: what about this question? should i answer it? or would you like to ?

Comment: You did all the hard part - you answer it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just ran into this issue, too. As long as I did not escape the spaces and used single or double quotes, I was able to use a root path with spaces.

the following works

```
root "/directory/with spaces not escaped/will work"
```

this does not work

```
root "/directory/with\ escaped\ spaces/will\ not\ work"
```

Comment: Doesn't work any more with `ssl_certificates` option.

Using nginx 1.16.1.